# Como funciona cada valor que pode ser usado no atributo "transition" (transition-timing-function) do CSS?

Tags: css3, animação

Geralmente quando quero fazer uma `transition` para animar um elemento em CSS, costumo usar o valor `linear` logo após a definição do tempo que quero numa animação.

Exemplo:

```css
.boing-boing{

height: 100px;
width: 200px;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;

background-color: aquamarine;

display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;


transition: background-color .3s linear, color .6s linear;
}


.boing-boing:hover{
   background-color: steelblue;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="boing-boing">
   faz um hover aí!
</div>
```

Porém fiquei sabendo da existência de outros valores ao invés do `linear`, que são `ease`, `ease-in`, `ease-in-out`, `step-start`, `step-end`, `steps` e `cubic-bezier` (esse último me deixou mais curioso, por causa do nome).

Poderiam me explicar do que se trata cada um, com exemplos, para eu poder a diferença?

Eu sempre uso o `linear` nas minhas transições, mas tenho interesse em saber mais sobre as outras.

Sei que o valor `transition` é um "resumo" das definições para uma animação e sei também que esse valor pode ser atribuido separadamente à `transition-timing-function`.

<sub>Achei muito incompleto os exemplos da w3schools.</sub>

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta ótima, mas logo te digo, alguns dos exemplos terão uma longa explicação, por isso acho que seria legal esperar o máximo de tempo para aceitar qualquer resposta, deixar essa pergunta em aberto será muito útil a comunidade (opinião pessoal apenas).

Comment: ps: vou publicas a resposta depois, pois ela esta muito meia-boca :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Transition timing function

O `transition-timing-function` define a forma como uma transformação é aplicada ao longo do tempo. Se é aplicada de forma constante ou mais rápido/devagar em determinada parte.

Exemplo:

Imagine que estamos a transformar a posição de um elemento, e por isso a movimenta-lo, ele não tem que se movimentar sempre à mesma velocidade. Pode ir mais rápido numas partes e mais lento noutras.

Antes de analisar as várias opções deixo aqui a nota que:

- `linear`
- `ease`
- `ease-in`
- `ease-out`
- `ease-in-out`

São casos particulares de `cubic-bezier` e por isso representáveis apenas com `cubic-bezier`. Eles foram criados para que fosse mais simples de se aplicar um `transition-timing-function` sem ter que se configurar vários valores.

## Linear

Este é o mais simples, e representa uma animação constante ao longo do tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O gráfico mostra o quanto o valor da propriedade muda em relação ao tempo. O eixo dos `x` representa o tempo, e o eixo do `y` representa a propriedade animada, seja esta `color`, `background-color`, `left`, etc...

Os gráficos tem como limites `0` e `1` pois são percentuais, logo `0` representa `0%` e `1` representa `100%`.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s linear; /*linear*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

Enquadrando esta animação com o gráfico, teríamos como propriedade `margin-left`. Logo iria representar o quanto o `margin-left` muda à medida que o tempo avança. Olhando para o gráfico que representa `y = x` vê-se que o `margin-left` aumenta em proporção com o tempo dando uma animação constante ao longo do tempo.

## Ease In

Lento no inicio e vai acelerando até normalizar no fim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note no entanto que a curva é bastante suave, logo o efeito é muito subtil, mas olhando com atenção vê-se que é mais rápido no inicio.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s ease-in; /*ease-in*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

## Ease Out

Este é normal no inicio e vai abrandando no fim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim como o anterior este efeito também é bastante subtil.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s ease-out; /*ease-out*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

## Ease In Out

Este é uma combinação dos dois ficando lento no inicio, normal a meio e lento no fim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s ease-in-out; /*ease-in-out*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

## Ease

Muito parecido ao `ease-in-out` mas com a diferença de que acelera mais rapidamente no inicio, e começa a abrandar a menos de metade do caminho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s ease; /*ease*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

## Cubic Bezier

Define a transição na forma de:

```
cubic-bezier (x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Em que implica que temos 2 pontos dados tanto em `x`, o tempo, como em `y` o valor da propriedade.

Logo um `cubic-bezier` de `(0.1,0.45,0.8,1)` indica que a `10%` do tempo o valor da propriedade vai a `45%` e a `80%` do tempo o valor já vai nos `100%`.

Isto permite representar animações bem mais personalizadas!

Como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que é bastante rápido no inicio, muito lento no meio, e bastante rápido no fim.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.035,0.99,0.99,0.09); /*cubic-bezier*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

Assim como mencionei atrás todas as outras funções de transição são construídas á base desta. Segue uma lista destas e respetiva correspondência em `cubic-bezier`:

- `linear` - `cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1)`
- `ease-in` - `cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)`
- `ease-out` - `cubic-bezier(0,0,0.58,1)`
- `ease-in-out` - `cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1)`
- `ease` - `cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1)`

Isto também permite criar variantes dos tipos representaveis por `cubic-bezier` mas mais notórios.

Como exemplo, podia-se criar uma versão bem mais evidente do `ease-in` com:

```
cubic-bezier(0.9,0,1,1)
```

Cujo gráfico seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.9,0,1,1); /*cubic-bezier*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

## Steps

Define a animação à custa de passos dividindo o espaço de tempo pela quantidade de passos. Também tem em consideração se a animação é feita no inicio ou no fim daquele passo.

A notação é :

```
steps(quantidade, start | end);
```

#### Start

Com `start` a animação é definida no inicio de cada passo.

Exemplificando, `steps(4, start)` indica que a animação tem 4 passos e é feita no inicio.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s steps(4,start); /*steps start*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

#### End

Na variante `end` a animação é definida no fim de cada passo, e segue a mesma sintaxe que a anterior apenas trocando a palavra `start` por `end`

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const cs = document.getElementById("caixa").style;
  cs.marginLeft = cs.marginLeft == "300px" ? "0px" : "300px";
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightBlue;
  transition: margin-left 1.5s steps(7,end); /*steps end*/
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"></div>
```

Links relevantes:

- [Transition timing function no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function)
- [Gerador de Cubic Bezier](http://cubic-bezier.com) - com este pode arrastar visualmente os manipulos que aparecem na página e gera o valor que tem de usar no `cubic-bezier`
- [Ou o gerador de Cubic Bezier do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Cubic_Bezier_Generator)
- [Transition timing function no W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp) - apesar de não ser tão bom, ainda tem informação relevante

<sub>Nota: Peço desculpa pelo *CSS* do snippet estar formatado de forma estranha, mas foi para ocupar menos espaço uma vez que a resposta é bastante grande.</sub>