# Como movimentar uma label html utilizando transições css

Tags: html, css, css-transições

Eu gostaria de movimentar a `label` ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>WOOOW</title>
    <style media="screen">
        img{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            transition: width 2s, height 2s;
        }
        img:hover{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        label{
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            transition: margin-bottom 2s;
        }
        img:hover > label{
            margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
        </img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Item 2</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Item 3</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Item 4</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239722/como-funciona-cada-valor-que-pode-ser-usado-no-atributo-transition-transition/240057#240057. Fale se tiver dúvidas

Comment: Com CSS3 ou Javascript (jQuery)??

Comment: Apenas com CSS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguns detalhes no seu CSS, por exemplo o seletor para pegar a label depois da imagem não deve ser o  <kbd>></kbd>  deve ser o  <kbd>+</kbd>  pois vc quer pegar o **label irmão** da imagem *e não dentro* da imagem.

Aqui vc pode ler sobre eles https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletores_CSS

Além disso o `margin-botton` não vai funcionar no `label`. A minha sugestão seria colocar `positon:relative` no label e depois usar apenas o `bottom` para fazer o efeito oque vc quer.

Veja como ficou no exemplo abaixo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>WOOOW</title>
    <style media="screen">
        img{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            transition: width 2s, height 2s;
        }
        img:hover{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        label{
          position: relative;
            bottom: 0px;
            transition: 2s;
        }
        img:hover + label{
            bottom: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
        </img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Item 2</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Item 3</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Item 4</h2>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
        <label for="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, quaerat!</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```